# C# Generics not working as expected

Tags: c#, generics

We have a problem with the usage of generics. 
We have a generic collection of generic keyvalue pair which is defined as follows

```
public class KeyValueTemplate<K, V> : IGetIdentifier<K>
{
//...
}

public class KeyValueListTemplate<K, V> : ObservableCollection<KeyValueTemplate<K, V>>
{
//....
}

public class KeyValueStringListTemplate : KeyValueListTemplate<string,string> { }
```

We are using this in the code as follows

```
public class test
{

   public KeyValueStringListTemplate SetValuesList{get;set;}
   public ObservableCollection<IGetIdentifier<string>> GetList()
   {
     return SetValuesList;
   }

}
```

The complier is not accepting this. The error is

```
Cannot convert type 'KeyValueStringListTemplate' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<IGetIdentifier<string>>
```

Why?? Both the types are same to me.

Comment: Did you try to declare the types with direction to achieve covariance? public class KeyValueListTemplate<out K,out V> : ObservableCollection<KeyValueTemplate<K, V>>

Comment: As noted in one of replies, only with interfaces, not classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
public class KeyValueListTemplate<K, V> : ObservableCollection<KeyValueTemplate<K, V>>
```

defines a new type, `KeyValueListTemplate`, that is a subtype of `ObservableCollection`, so they are *different types*. `KeyValueListTemplate`can be safely converted to `ObservableCollection`, because it has a superset of `ObservableCollection`'s functionality (by Liskov Substitution Principle), but the opposite conversion is not safe.

Comment: If that is true, then a casting to the parent type should work. But it is not working

Comment: KeyValueListTemplatecan be safely converted to ObservableCollection? No. That is the problem

Comment: I think it can't be cast because the type parameter for ObservableCollection is not covariant.

Comment: Even if `A` is supertype of `B`, `GenericType<A>` is *not* a supertype of `GenericType<B>`. Safe casts can be achieved with covariance (`out` and `in` keywords), but only with interfaces, not classes.

Comment: It's actually a problem with the right hand side. If it was declared `KeyValueListTemplate<K, V> : ObservableCollection<IGetIdentifier<K>>`, then the rest of the code would work. The problem is that `KeyValueTemplate<X,V>` is not the same type parameter as `IGetIdentifier<K>`.

Comment: @Damien-KeyValueListTemplate<K, V> has its implementation  of KeyValueTemplate<K, V>, so cannot replace with the interface IGetIdentifier<K>.

Answer (score 1):

Its a matter of [covariance in generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx), which was not exposed to c#/vb.net before .net 4. 
While it seem trivial that you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>();
// An object that is instantiated with a more derived type argument 
// is assigned to an object instantiated with a less derived type argument. 
// Assignment compatibility is preserved. 
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
```

which is what your code is doing at the bottom line, it wasnt supported up to .net 4

The article i linked to explanis how to implement it and how it works.